# Make an API call inside of another API call?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I basically need to combine data from two different API calls. Here is what I have right now:

```
    var url= "https://website.com/api.json";
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: 'json',
        headers: {'X-API-Key': 'xxxxxx'},
        success: function(data){

            var api = data.results[0].api;

            for (var i=0;i<api.length;++i)
            var api2url = api[i].api2url;

            {
                $('tbody').append('<tr><td>'+api[i].thing+'</td></tr>');
            }
        }
    });
```

The above works.

The problem is that I also need data from https://website.com/api2.json (which will come from data from the api1 call). I need my final code to look like:

`$('tbody').append('<tr><td><a href="'+api2[i].thing+'">+api[i].thing+'</a></td></tr>');`

Comment: Do you need any data from api1 to make the call to api2?

Comment: Yes, I actually do. The api call url will come directly from the api1 call.

Comment: So then you'll have to execute that call originating from inside the first's success callback so you'd have access to the url you need, and then you'd do the combined results logic inside the success of the second ajax call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way forward would be to make that API call in the success callback of your first API call.  Might look something like:

```
var url= "https://website.com/api.json";
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "GET",
    dataType: 'json',
    headers: {'X-API-Key': 'xxxxxx'},
    success: function(data){
      // now you have closure over results from api call one
      $.ajax({
        url: 'apiURL2', // or something
        type: "GET",
        dataType: 'json',
        headers: {'X-API-Key': data.results.apiKey // or something },
        success: function(moreData){

        var api = data.results[0].api;

        for (var i=0;i<api.length;++i)
        {
            $('tbody').append('<tr><td>'+api[i].thing+ moreData.thing'</td></tr>');
        }
    }
  })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const getDataFromApi = (endpoint) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "GET",
            dataType: 'json',
            headers: {'X-API-Key': 'xxxxxx'},
            success: (data) => {
                return resolve(data);
            }
        }); 
    });
};

Promise.all([
    return getDataFromApi('https://website.com/api.json');
]).then((data) => {
    return Promise.all([
        data,
        getDataFromApi('https://website.com/api2.json')
    ]);
    // here your business logic (for loop in your code)
}).then((data) => { // with bluebird it's easier use spread
    const dataApi1 = data[0];
    const dataApi2 = data[1];
})
.catch((err) => {
    console.error(err);
});
```

Comment: If you look at the comments it does mention he needs data from api call 1 to construct api call 2

Comment: Fixed, i adapted the code to do it using promises chaining the result

Comment: Even you can adapt this code to return an array of dynamic calls to your endpoints (coming from data1 for example)

Answer (score 0):

You can make the second ajax call on the success of the first.  Then perform your DOM updates as needed.  But the idea is to run the second ajax call once the first has completed and was successful.

```
function callApi2(aip1) {
    $.ajax({
        //params for the call
        url: api1.api2url,
        success: function(data) {
            var api2 = data.results[0].api; // or whatever the property is
            $('tbody').append('<tr><td><a href="'+api2[i].thing+'">'+api1.thing+'</a></td></tr>');

        }, 
    });
}

var url= "https://website.com/api.json";
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "GET",
    dataType: 'json',
    headers: {'X-API-Key': 'xxxxxx'},
    success: function(data){
        var api1 = data.results[0].api;
        for (var i=0; i<api1.length;++i){
            callApi2(api1[i]);
        }
    }
});
```