# How to make an api call inside an api with a url obtained from first api?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to make two api calls. The first call obtains the url I need for the second call.

I need data from both api calls. From the first call, I need data from multiple endpoints. For the second api call, I only need data from one endpoint.

Right now, I am making my second api call inside the for loop of my first call. Obviously my code does not work and I am not even sure if that's the correct way to go about getting what I need. Here is what I have so far:

```
    var url= "https://api.propublica.org/congress/v1/members/xxx/votes.json";
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: 'json',
        headers: {'X-API-Key': 'xxx'},
        success: function(data){
            var votes = data.results[0].votes;

            for (var i=0; i<votes.length;++i){
                var api2 = votes[i].bill.bill_uri;          

                $.ajax({
                    url: 'api2',
                    type: "GET",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    headers: {'X-API-Key': 'xxx'},
                    success: function(moreData){

                        var billUrl = moreData.results[0].congressdotgov_url;

                        for (var a=0;a<billUrl.length;++i)
                        {
                            $('.recent-votes tbody').append('<tr><td><a href="'+billUrl[a]+'">'+votes[i].bill.number+'</a></td></tr>');
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

edit: Here is the response I am getting from the api calls:

votes.json:

```
{
    "status": "OK",
    "copyright": "Copyright (c) 2017 Pro Publica Inc. All Rights Reserved.",
    "results": [{
        "member_id": "xxx",
        "num_results": "20",
        "offset": "0",
        "votes": [{
                "member_id": "xxx",
                "chamber": "House",
                "congress": "115",
                "session": "1",
                "roll_call": "664",
                "vote_uri": "https://api.propublica.org/congress/v1/115/house/sessions/1/votes/664.json",
                "bill": {
                    "bill_id": "hconres90-115",
                    "number": "H CON RES 90",
                    "sponsor_id": "C001038",
                    "bill_uri": "https://api.propublica.org/congress/v1/115/bills/hconres90.json",
                    "title": "Condemning ethnic cleansing of the Rohingya and calling for an end to the attacks in and an immediate restoration of humanitarian access to the state of Rakhine in Burma.",
                    "latest_action": "The title of the measure was amended. Agreed to without objection."
                },
                "amendment": {},
                "description": "Condemning ethnic cleansing of the Rohingya and calling for an end to the attacks in and an immediate restoration of humanitarian access to the state of Rakhine in Burma",
                "question": "On Motion to Suspend the Rules and Agree, as Amended",
                "result": "Passed",
                "date": "2017-12-06",
                "time": "16:50:00",
                "total": {
                    "yes": 423,
                    "no": 3,
                    "present": 0,
                    "not_voting": 6
                },
                "position": "Yes"
            },
            {
                "member_id": "xxx",
                "chamber": "House",
                "congress": "115",
                "session": "1",
                "roll_call": "662",
                "vote_uri": "https://api.propublica.org/congress/v1/115/house/sessions/1/votes/662.json",
                "bill": {
                    "bill_id": "hr38-115",
                    "number": "H R 38",
                    "sponsor_id": "H001067",
                    "bill_uri": "https://api.propublica.org/congress/v1/115/bills/hr38.json",
                    "title": "To amend title 18, United States Code, to provide a means by which nonresidents of a State whose residents may carry concealed firearms may also do so in the State.",
                    "latest_action": "Motion to reconsider laid on the table Agreed to without objection."
                },
                "amendment": {},
                "description": "Concealed Carry Reciprocity Act of 2017",
                "question": "On Motion to Recommit with Instructions",
                "result": "Failed",
                "date": "2017-12-06",
                "time": "16:34:00",
                "total": {
                    "yes": 190,
                    "no": 236,
                    "present": 0,
                    "not_voting": 6
                },
                "position": "No"
            },
            {
                "member_id": "xxx",
                "chamber": "House",
                "congress": "115",
                "session": "1",
                "roll_call": "661",
                "vote_uri": "https://api.propublica.org/congress/v1/115/house/sessions/1/votes/661.json",
                "bill": {
                    "bill_id": "s1266-115",
                    "number": "S 1266",
                    "sponsor_id": "I000024",
                    "bill_uri": "https://api.propublica.org/congress/v1/115/bills/s1266.json",
                    "title": "A bill to authorize the Secretary of Veterans Affairs to enter into contracts with nonprofit organizations to investigate medical centers of the Department of Veterans Affairs.",
                    "latest_action": "Motion to reconsider laid on the table Agreed to without objection."
                },
                "amendment": {},
                "description": "Enhancing Veteran Care Act",
                "question": "On Motion to Suspend the Rules and Pass",
                "result": "Passed",
                "date": "2017-12-06",
                "time": "14:35:00",
                "total": {
                    "yes": 423,
                    "no": 0,
                    "present": 0,
                    "not_voting": 9
                },
                "position": "Yes"
            },
            {
                "member_id": "xxx",
                "chamber": "House",
                "congress": "115",
                "session": "1",
                "roll_call": "653",
                "vote_uri": "https://api.propublica.org/congress/v1/115/house/sessions/1/votes/653.json",
                "bill": {
                    "bill_id": "hr1-115",
                    "number": "H R 1",
                    "sponsor_id": "B000755",
                    "bill_uri": "https://api.propublica.org/congress/v1/115/bills/hr1.json",
                    "title": "To provide for reconciliation pursuant to title II of the concurrent resolution on the budget for fiscal year 2018.",
                    "latest_action": "Motion by Senator Booker to instruct Senate conferees (health insurance) rejected in Senate by Yea-Nay Vote. 47 - 51. Record Vote Number: 309."
                },
                "amendment": {},
                "description": "Tax Cuts and Jobs Act",
                "question": "On Motion to go to Conference",
                "result": "Passed",
                "date": "2017-12-04",
                "time": "19:04:00",
                "total": {
                    "yes": 222,
                    "no": 192,
                    "present": 0,
                    "not_voting": 19
                },
                "position": "Yes"
            },
            {
                "member_id": "xxx",
                "chamber": "House",
                "congress": "115",
                "session": "1",
                "roll_call": "645",
                "vote_uri": "https://api.propublica.org/congress/v1/115/house/sessions/1/votes/645.json",
                "bill": {
                    "bill_id": "hres635-115",
                    "number": "H RES 635",
                    "sponsor_id": "W000810",
                    "bill_uri": "https://api.propublica.org/congress/v1/115/bills/hres635.json",
                    "title": "Providing for consideration of the bill (H.R. 4182) to amend title 5, United States Code, to modify probationary periods with respect to positions within the competitive service and the Senior Executive Service, and for other purposes, and providing for consideration of the bill (H.R. 1699) to amend the Truth in Lending Act to modify the definitions of a mortgage originator and a high-cost mortgage, to amend the Secure and Fair Enforcement for Mortgage Licensing Act of 2008 to modify the definition of a loan originator, and for other purposes.",
                    "latest_action": "Motion to reconsider laid on the table Agreed to without objection."
                },
                "amendment": {},
                "description": "Providing for consideration of H.R. 4182, the Ensuring a Qualified Civil Service Act of 2017; and H.R. 1699, the Preserving Access to Manufactured Housing Act of 2017",
                "question": "On Agreeing to the Resolution",
                "result": "Passed",
                "date": "2017-11-30",
                "time": "14:15:00",
                "total": {
                    "yes": 226,
                    "no": 186,
                    "present": 0,
                    "not_voting": 21
                },
                "position": "Yes"
            }
        ]
    }]
}
```

For each individual bill uri api call, I'm seeing the header status code is 200 but the response tab is showing "This request has no response data available".

The end result html should look like:

$('.recent-votes tbody').append(''+votes[i].bill.number+'');

```
<tr><td><a href="www.billurl.com/1">Bill 1</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="www.billurl.com/2">Bill 2</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="www.billurl.com/3">Bill 3</a></td></tr>
etc.
etc.
```

Comment: Put your second AJAX call into it's own function. Fire that function in the success method of the first call when needed. You can pass URLs as parameters when you call the second ajax function from the first.

Comment: `url: 'api2',` should be `url: api2,` referencing the **variable** and not a string.

Comment: Is there any way you could rework your first GET request to retrieve the data you need and do all of the work server side?

Comment: @ProEvilz that's what the OP is doing - just without the external function definition

Comment: You asked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47684311/make-an-api-call-inside-of-another-api-call/), there are three answers to that question.  I tailored my answer to your question and updated it once you updated your question.  It appears you copied/pasted the answer you accepted in that question into this question.  It might be better to comment on the answer and get feedback from the person who wrote that code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make an API call inside of another API call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47684311/make-an-api-call-inside-of-another-api-call)

Comment: Thanks @ppovoski I'll make the comment there. I was building off of an answer I got in that question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code actually looks *mostly* sound. This is a viable way to achieve what you are trying to do. However, It looks like you have a typo in your inner loop. You are incrementing `i`, when you should be incrementing `a`. That's in this line:

```
    for (var a=0;a<billUrl.length;++i)
```

Secondly, change your `++i` to `i++` (do the same for `a`). Otherwise, you will be skipping the very first item in each loop. Thirdly, it looks like you are not using the assigned `api2` variable in your inner loop calls. Remove the quotes from that.

Finally, your `i` variable is out of scope when you get to success function of your inner loop. This is the trickiest part. There are numerous ways to handle this, and some examples are here: [jQuery ajax loop and iteration scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20333133/jquery-ajax-loop-and-iteration-scope). In my opinion, the simplest way is to use closures and wrap your `i` variable.

Try this:

```
var url= "https://api.propublica.org/congress/v1/members/xxx/votes.json";
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "GET",
    dataType: 'json',
    headers: {'X-API-Key': 'xxx'},
    success: function(data){
        var votes = data.results[0].votes;
        for (var i=0; i<votes.length;i++){
            var api2 = votes[i].bill.bill_uri;
            (function(i) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: api2,
                    type: "GET",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    headers: {'X-API-Key': 'xxx'},
                    success: function(moreData){
                        var billUrl = moreData.results[0].congressdotgov_url;
                        for (var a=0;a<billUrl.length;a++)
                        {
                            $('.recent-votes tbody').append('<tr><td><a href="'+billUrl[a]+'">'+votes[i].bill.number+'</a></td></tr>');
                        }
                    }
                });
            })(i);
        }
    }
});
```

There are other ways to do this as well. As others have suggested, you can return everything you need from your first api call (if you have control of the backend). Obviously, this would be the best and most efficient thing to do, if it's possible. However, if you don't have control over the backend, then these fixes should get you going.

Comment: In the second AJAX call, it still says `url: 'api2',` while it should be `url: api2,`

Comment: Thanks for catching that. I'm getting an error though: votes[i] is undefined.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @Luca. I didn't catch that. Updated.

Comment: @user715564, in that case, you'll need to take a look at your data that's coming back. Maybe you could post a sample of the data you recieve. Are you familiar with F12 debugging tools?

Comment: @user715564 Have you tried looking at what the API sends back to you? Is there even a votes array?

Comment: @luca Yes there is a votes array https://projects.propublica.org/api-docs/congress-api/members/#get-a-specific-members-vote-positions

Comment: Another question, should there be a for loop in the second call? There should only be one "billUrl". I'm trying to list out the votes. The bill url is the link to the bill's page that was voted on.

Comment: @user715564 I would suggest looking at the real data you are getting back and debugging it. If you can post it here, that would be helpful.

Comment: Did you mean me? or @user715564?

Comment: Sorry, yes, I meant @user715564.

Comment: @MattSpinks What specifically would you like? I can post a screenshot of the network tab in the Chrome inspection tools. Would that help?

Comment: You should be able to copy/paste the content into a code block (as long as it's not too big).

Comment: Ok, I updated my original question. Let me know if that's what you needed. Here is a link to the response for each individual bill https://projects.propublica.org/api-docs/congress-api/bills/#get-a-specific-bill

Comment: Thanks @user715564. Just to be clear, is this the result you are getting back from your first call? or the second call?

Comment: The response pasted in my question is from the first call. The link in my previous comment is what the response should be for the second call.

Comment: @user715564 according some my own testing, your outer loop is fine. But I didn't see that you were using `i` inside your inner loop. That's going to cause issues. `i` becomes out of scope when your inner loop executes. That's probably why `votes[i]` is undefined. You'll need to wrap it in a closure, or use some other method. Check my updated answer.

Comment: @MattSpinks Ok that's kind of working. There is still an issue with the loops. Each bill number has a link of the first character in the url of the first bill uri. For example `<tr><td><a href="h">H CON RES 90</a></td></tr><tr><td><a href="t">H CON RES 90</a></td></tr><tr><td><a href="t">H CON RES 90</a></td></tr><tr><td><a href="p">H CON RES 90</a></td></tr><tr><td><a href="s">H CON RES 90</a></td></tr>` Got it working by just removing the second loop. Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: Awesome. Great to hear. That was a confusing one.